# Java example for checked vs unchecked exception

Tags: java, exception

Is this statement/example valid for checked and unchecked exception?

Unchecked Exception: 
The exceptions that are not checked at compile time are called unchecked exceptions.
Example:

```
 public class UncheckedException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int value = 10/0;
        }
    }
```

Checked Exception:
The exceptions that are checked at compile time are called Checked exceptions.
Example:

```
public class CheckedException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
                int value = 10/0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Caught " + e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please describe your question clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not a valid example / illustration.  In both cases the exception that is thrown is an unchecked exception.

The difference between checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions is the exception class.

- `ArithmeticException` is always an unchecked exception because it extends `RuntimeException`
- `IOException` is a checked exception because it does not extend `RuntimeException` (or `Error`).

The fact that you do or don't catch the exception doesn't change its nature.

---

At the risk of repeating myself:

> Unchecked Exception: The exceptions that are not checked at compile time are called unchecked exceptions.
>
> Checked Exception: The exceptions that are checked at compile time are called Checked exceptions.

These are both incorrect definitions.

---

See also: [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)